# Custom Typehandler for differents result properties

Tags: java, biginteger, ibatis

I'm using iBatis 2.0 and I have problems using my own typeHandler in 2 properties of type BIGINT. The result map es like this:

```
<resultMap id="getList" class="Something">
    <result property="property1" column="property1" jdbcType="BIGINT" javaType="java.math.BigInteger" typeHandler="BigIntegerTypeHandler"/>
    <result property="property2" column="property2" jdbcType="BIGINT" javaType="java.math.BigInteger" typeHandler="BigIntegerTypeHandler"/>
</resultMap>
```

The TypeHandler I'm using is this one:

```
public class BigIntegerTypeHandler implements TypeHandlerCallback {

    public Object getResult (ResultGetter getter) throws SQLException{
        if(getter.wasNull()){
            return null;
        }

        Object o = getter.getObject();
        if(o instanceof BigDecimal){
            BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) o;
            return bd.toBigInteger();
        }else if(o instanceof BigInteger){
            return (BigInteger) o;
        }else{
            return o;
        }
    }

    public void setParameter(ParameterSetter setter, Object parameter) throws SQLException{
        if(parameter == null){
            setter.setNull(Types.BIGINT);
        }else{
            BigInteger i = (BigInteger) parameter;
            setter.setBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(i));
        }
    }

    public Object valueOf(String s){
        return s;
    }
}
```

I've used this type handler in others requests and i didn't have any problem (when it was only one property of type BigInt). But when I've tried to use it twice in *property1* and *property2* I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
The error occurred in myxmlfile.xml.  
The error occurred while applying a result map.  
Check the myxmlfile.getListBigInt.  
The error happened while setting a property on the result object.  
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error setting property 'property2' of '{dataId:438 property1:null property2:118 costo:0 isLoaded:false origenDestino:{0-0H:47571}'.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

The setter of the class *Something* is:

```
public void setProperty1(BigInteger property1) {
    this.property1  = property1;
    this.property2 = new MagicObject(this.property1,this.property2);
}
```

All I know is that the second line of the setter is generating the conflict, but I don't know why. Anybody could help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Sebastián.

Comment: I know the error (NullPointer) is because one of the properties is NULL. The problem is...none of the properties is NULL so I should have 2 values for the 2 properties. Instead, I'm getting only one value for only 1 property.

Comment: Even when the property is not null the getter.wasNull() is true and then returns the null. Try removing that and see if it works

Comment: Couldnt edit previous comment. Check the bigintegerhandler of MyBatis for the correct implementation

Comment: Does it also reproducible on fres MyBatis implementations?